# Hide POS RewardButton from js. Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

From template 'RewardButton'  :

```
 <t t-name="RewardButton" owl="1">
        <span class="control-button" t-att-class="is_available()? 'highlight' : ''">
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            <span> </span>
            <span>Reward</span>
        </span>
    </t>
```

I want to hide template in js code;
How can I do it using :

```
 $('.RewardButton').('hide');
```

Thanks.